# vsCode gives a warning on apparently valid code from vue.js docs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Using Visual Studio Code 1.13.1V and [following vue.js guide for lazi-loading](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/lazy-loading.html) , when i'm writing this line of code:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
const Health = () => import('@/components/health')
```

vscode throws the following problems:

```
file: 'file:///c%3A/projects/vue-lazy-loading/src/router/index.js'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Expression expected.'
at: '3,22'
source: 'js'

file: 'file:///c%3A/projects/vue-lazy-loading/src/router/index.js'
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Variable declaration expected.'
at: '3,28'
source: 'js'
```

visually, that's how it looks:
[image]

is there something wrong with the code, or with VS-code?
what is the correct way to write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/25003) with support for **dynamic imports** in Javascript with Visual Studio Code, which uses Typescript to parse Javascript.

> Yes, this is currently not supported. Microsoft/TypeScript#14495
>   tracks this issue on the TypeScript side. We use TypeScript to power
>   both our JS and TS language features.

Dynamic imports are a [new Javascript feature](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import) at [Stage 3](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-dynamic-import/) of the [TC39 process](https://tc39.github.io/process-document/). As it is not yet finished, some tools are still working on support for it.

A fix seems to be [in the works](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/28450#issuecomment-307847099).

> Typescript 2.4 should include support for dynamic imports:
>   Microsoft/TypeScript#14495
>
> We plan on picking up TS 2.4 for VSCode 1.14 in June and it should be
>   available in the insiders builds soon
>
> There is currently no way to suppress this error specifically.
>   Normally you can add // @ts-ignore before the error line to disable
>   error checking but this does not work for syntax errors like the
>   dynamic imports one

Comment: Perhaps as a work around you could just use `require()` instead of `import()`? I think that should probably do the same thing and not confuse the TypeScript parser.